# Why is the first nested iteration faster than subsequent ones?

Tags: java, performance

Test application:

```
public class Main {

    private static long a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (long j = 0; j < 5000000000L; j++) a++;
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }

        System.out.println("\na = " + a);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
2600
3739
3735
3734
3742
```

I noticed that the first nested iteration is considerably faster than subsequent ones whenever I run the program.

Why is it so?

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT**

If I copy-paste the outer loop right below the first one:

```
public class Main {

    private static long a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (long j = 0; j < 5000000000L; j++) a++;
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }

        System.out.println("----");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (long j = 0; j < 5000000000L; j++) a++;
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }

        System.out.println("\na = " + a);
    }
}
```

then again the first iteration is the fastest in both outer loops:

```
2587
3736
3736
3734
3732
----
2560
3737
3734
3735
3740
```

Even in the first example, I would expect the first iteration to be slower, because of warm-up time (initialization, JIT optimizations, etc), as described in the answers for [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) which @Mureinik kindly pointed to, but it is the opposite.

**EDIT 2**

When I increase the limit for `j` variable by adding another zero to it (ten times), the difference is more than 10 seconds:

```
25747
38637
37767
38104
38690
----
27951
38780
39035
37962
37931
```

It seems to be a constant ratio of about `2.6/3.7`.

Comment: I get different output that yours: `3410, 3547, 3386, 3415, 3324`, JVM 1.8

Comment: @AlexShesterov I'm observing the similar behaviour with Oracle java 7 also. What is the jvm provider you use?

Comment: @Mureinik I edited my question. Now everything seems to be according to the rules mentioned in the answers of the question you pointed to. You still consider this as a duplicate?

Comment: It's a duplicate of ['Why is this inner loop 4X faster the first iteration through the outer loop?'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527387/why-is-this-inner-loop-4x-faster-the-first-iteration-through-the-outer-loop), not the one mentioned by @Mureinik.

Comment: @apangin Indeed, thanks!. It may be that static `a` variable is cached in the register in the first iteration in this case.